# MySQL field DATETIME truncates ISO8601

Tags: mysql, import, mariadb, truncation

Having MySQL/MariaDB table created like

```
CREATE TABLE `testTable` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timeinfo` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And inserted with full ISO8601 value like this:

```
MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO testTable VALUES (1, '2500-12-31T00:00:00.000Z');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> show warnings;
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                       |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'timeinfo' at row 1 |
+---------+------+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from testTable;
+----+---------------------+
| id | timeinfo            |
+----+---------------------+
|  1 | 2500-12-31 00:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I don't exactly see what is being truncated, the "Z" as in ZULU TimeZone ?

---

Is it possible to contain the information fully in MySQL/MariaDB field type?

If so which field data type should be used?

Comment: looks to me the fractional seconds was truncated.. in MySQL 5.7 and MariaDB 5.3 you can enable fractional seconds support with ``timeinfo` datetime(3) DEFAULT NULL,`  notice the (3) after datetime.

Comment: @RaymondNijland thank you, that is technically correct, but still the insert is being truncated of timezone, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database expects another input that is why you get the warning

**In MySQL DATETIME needs the following format**

> DATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS

**This will not produce any warnings:**

```
INSERT INTO testTable VALUES (, '2500-12-31 00:00:00');
```

Even with your warnings the database will fill you record.

Comment: Can I get rid of the warning of imezone being truncated somehow? I don't need the timezone information stored, because TIMEZONE of DB-instance/server is the same as all data inserted. Thank you

Comment: From where do you get these values and are you using any language for this or are you storing manually into the database?

Comment: @Noob interesting that in MySQL 5.7 you can use "T" as separator between date and time values: 2517-08-22T16:55:55

Comment: @Noob I get that I can rid of the warning by modifying the data, but I'm looking for a way, without touching the data. Such as setting the DB instance so it does ignore timezone or does not emit warning in this specific cases. I'm doing bulk load from CSV data (LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE).

Comment: I am unsure if this is possible technically you should check MySQL documentation i guess

Answer (score 3):

'Z' is a [special time zone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC). It means "The time is in UTC timezone".

MySQL 5.7 datetime and timestamp types are unable to store timezone information. MySQL does not understand "Z".

If you need to store timezone, use additional field.

Comment: Can I get rid of the warning somehow? I don't need the timezone information stored, because TIMEZONE of DB-instance/server is the same as all data inserted. Thank you

Comment: @MarekSebera easy.

`insert into testTable  values( 1, replace('2017-08-22T16:55:55.000Z','Z','') );`

Comment: I get that I can rid of the warning by modifying the data, but I'm looking for a way, without touching the data. Such as setting the DB instance so it does ignore timezone or does not emit warning in this specific cases. I'm doing bulk load from CSV data.

Comment: You can not get rid of the warning. You can only turn all warnings off.  :) If you can't process your CSV file with SED/AWK before,  I suggest you can load the datetime info into a new  VARCHAR field. After the import  do an update timeinfo=replace(oldfield, ... ) .