# MySQL field DATETIME truncates despite correct format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, xampp

I'm currently trying to load data from `reloads.csv` into my database.
But the DATETIME fields gets truncated. I took care to get the correct date format as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45817809/mysql-field-datetime-truncates-iso8601).

When I load the data, I get this kind of error:

> Connected successfully
>   537,496,3,4,4.36186,50.86034,4.372,50.86309,2017-01-01T22:05:55,2017-01-02T05:02:20 
>   248,129,2,4,4.37052,50.86135,4.36254,50.82652,2017-01-01T23:56:45,2017-01-02T05:05:33 Error: INSERT INTO Reloads (scooter, user, initialLoad, finalLoad, sourceX, sourceY, destinationX, destinationY, startTime, endTime) VALUES ('248', '129','2', '4', '4.37052', '50.86135', '4.36254','50.82652', '2017-01-01 23:56:45', '2017-01-02 05:05:33 ')
>   Duplicate entry '2017-01-01' for key 'PRIMARY'
>   363,17,1,4,4.36902,50.87497,4.3785,50.87691,2017-01-01T22:00:52,2017-01-02T05:08:34 Error: INSERT INTO Reloads (scooter, user, initialLoad, finalLoad, sourceX, sourceY, destinationX, destinationY, startTime, endTime) VALUES ('363', '17','1', '4', '4.36902', '50.87497', '4.3785','50.87691', '2017-01-01 22:00:52', '2017-01-02 05:08:34 ')
>   Duplicate entry '2017-01-01' for key 'PRIMARY'
>   ...

reloads.csv has the following structure:

```
scooter, user, initialLoad, finalLoad, sourceX, sourceY, destinationX, 
destinationY, startTime, endTime
537,496,3,4,4.36186,50.86034,4.372,50.86309,2017-01-01T22:05:55,2017-01-02T05:02:20
248,129,2,4,4.37052,50.86135,4.36254,50.82652,2017-01-01T23:56:45,2017-01-02T05:05:33
363,17,1,4,4.36902,50.87497,4.3785,50.87691,2017-01-01T22:00:52,2017-01-02T05:08:34
...
```

I created the Reloads table like this:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE Reloads (
        scooter INT NOT NULL,
        user INT NOT NULL,
        initialLoad INT,
        finalLoad INT,
        sourceX FLOAT,
        sourceY FLOAT,
        destinationX FLOAT,
        destinationY FLOAT,
        startTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
        endTime DATETIME,
        PRIMARY KEY (startTime),
        FOREIGN KEY (scooter) REFERENCES Scooters(numero),
        FOREIGN KEY (user) REFERENCES Rechargeurs(ID)
)";
```

And here is how a load reloads into the Reloads table:

```
//INSERT RELOADS IN DB
if ($fh = fopen("../../data2019/reloads.csv", 'r')) {
  $line = fgets($fh);//remove first line
  $sql = "";
  while (!feof($fh)) {
    $line = fgets($fh);
    echo "<br>" . $line;
    //echo $line;
    $str_arr = explode(",", $line);
    //print_r($str_arr);
    if (count($str_arr) == 10) {
      $startTime = str_replace("T", " ",$str_arr[8]);
      $endTime = str_replace("T", " ",$str_arr[9]);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO Reloads (scooter, user, initialLoad, finalLoad, sourceX, sourceY, destinationX, destinationY,
startTime, endTime)
      VALUES (
              '$str_arr[0]',
              '$str_arr[1]',
              '$str_arr[2]',
              '$str_arr[3]',
              '$str_arr[4]',
              '$str_arr[5]',
              '$str_arr[6]',
              '$str_arr[7]',
              '$startTime',
              '$endTime'
      )";
      if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        //echo "\nNew record created successfully";
      } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
      }
    }
  }
  fclose($fh);
}
```

I have no more idea of how to debug and resolve the problem. All datetimes are truncated in this form in my database: `2017-01-01`

Thanks in advance

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I just tried it, however, I get all the datetime in this form now `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00`

Comment: From the error message I would guess that it's `DATE` and not `DATETIME`. The queries work for me [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rX46GtJQUwtpJwRuBHU3af/0)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel your comment helped me get the format I wanted but all entries have 00:00:00 at the end.

Comment: Well - The PHP code generates a correct SQL query (Though I don't know why there is a space at the end of the last column value `'2017-01-02 05:05:33 '`). The problem seems to be on the database. Double check the table schema (It really looks like `DATE`). Check if any triggers are defined for this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substr` and `strpos` to only get the date in Format `Y-m-d`, based on your data

```
$startTime = '2017-01-01T22:05:55';
$endTime   = '2017-01-02T05:08:34';
$startTime = substr($startTime,0,strpos($startTime, 'T'));
$endTime   = substr($endTime,0,strpos($endTime, 'T'));
```

You can use `DateTime` for `Y-m-d H:i:s`

```
$startTime  = '2017-01-01T22:05:55';
$dateObject = new DateTime($startTime);
$startTime  = $dateObject->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$endTime   = '2017-01-02T05:08:34';
$dateObject = new DateTime($endTime);
$endTime  = $dateObject->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: I want the full format so that I won't get duplicate primary keys when two loads happen the same day.

Comment: @Dixel do you mean like this 2017-01-01 22:05:55 ?